# End of New 52/DCYou Timeline

Tags: dc, dc-rebirth

I'm really confused about the end of the New 52/DCYou timeline leading up to Rebirth. There are a bunch of stories that seem to happen at roughly the same time, but where the characters are undergoing some transformation, and therefore have to be somewhat ordered. Does anyone have a definitive timeline with respect to the following stories?

- Darkseid War
- Superman Truth, Injustice, Savage Dawn, Death of Superman
- Batman Endgame, RoboBatman
- Green Lantern Renegade
- Green Lantern Corps Lost Army and Edge of Oblivion

The main confusion is particularly, around Hal Jordan, as we know he has Krona's Gauntlet at the beginning of Rebirth, but there is no mention of Jessica being a GL while he's a renegade.

Answer (score 1):

It's comics so timelines are always muddy at best when it comes to the same characters being in multiple books. The current Green Lanterns book with Jessica and Baz didn't fit until the current Green Lantern Corps book finished like 8 issues because Hal was back to using a ring and leading the corps.

A rough order of things would be

1. Endgame
2. Truth - Injustice - Renegade - Lost Army/Oblivion - Robobatman
3. Savage Dawn - Renegade - Lost Army/Oblivion - Robobatman
4. Darksied War
5. Death of Superman